# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write' "

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-storage

When working on Google Cloud Storage in Python I get this error:

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'"

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

model = None
interpreter = None
input_index = None
output_index = None

class_names = ["Early Blight", "Late Blight", "Healthy"]

BUCKET_NAME = "codebasics-tf-models"

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_file(destination_file_name)
    print(f"Blob {source_blob_name} downloaded to {destination_file_name}.")


def predict(request):
    global model
    if model is None:
        download_blob(
            BUCKET_NAME,
            "models/plant_disease.h5",
            "/tmp/plant_disease.h5",
        )
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/tmp/plant_disease.h5")

    image = request.files["file"]

    image = np.array(
        Image.open(image).convert("RGB").resize((256, 256))
    )
    image = image / 255
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)

    print("Prediction:", predictions)

    predictions = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = round(100 * (np.max(predictions[0])), 2)

    return {
        "class": predictions,
        "confidence": confidence
    }
```

And when I tried to run it in Postman it said:

> "500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the
> server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

And in GCP -> Logs this was the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 99, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 37, in predict
    download_blob(
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 31, in download_blob
    blob.download_to_file(destination_file_name)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1129, in download_to_file
    client.download_blob_to_file(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 1099, in download_blob_to_file
    blob_or_uri._do_download(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 984, in _do_download
    response = download.consume(transport, timeout=timeout)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 237, in consume
    return _request_helpers.wait_and_retry(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/_request_helpers.py", line 155, in wait_and_retry
    response = func()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 233, in retriable_request
    self._write_to_stream(result)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 124, in _write_to_stream
    self._stream.write(chunk)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 2):

`.download_to_file` expects a file (a file-like object to be precise, also called a stream - can be a file, can be e.g. io.BytesIO to keep it in memory), not path to file. So you actually gotta open the file you want for writing:

So instead of

```py
blob.download_to_file(destination_file_name)
```

You need:

```
with open(destination_file_name, 'wb') as f:
    blob.download_to_file(f)
```

The 'wb' means writing bytes mode.